# Intuition for why a 90 degree rotation of a vector about an arbitrary axis can be expressed as 3 90 degree rotations of the vector's projections.

Tags: geometry, vectors, rotations, cross-product, geometric-algebras

Given a unit vector $\hat{u}$ and a vector $\vec{v}$ perpendicular to $\hat{u}$, we can rotate $\vec{v}$ by 90 degrees around $\hat{u}$ with the cross product $\hat{u} \times \vec{v}$. Since the cross product is linear in its first argument this can be rewritten as:
$$\hat{u} \times \vec{v} = (u_x\hat{x} + u_y\hat{y} + u_z\hat{z}) \times \vec{v} = u_x(\hat{x} \times \vec{v}) + u_y(\hat{y} \times \vec{v}) + u_z(\hat{z} \times \vec{v})$$
The geometric interpretation is: project $\vec{v}$ onto the 3 coordinate planes (YZ, ZX, and XY), then rotate each projection 90 degrees in its respective plane, then weight these rotated projections by the components of $\hat{u}$, then sum them all up to get the rotated vector $\vec{v}$.

What I'm looking for is some sort of intuition or geometric picture illustrating why this works. I know it works because I can show it with the algebra but I'd like a deeper understanding of this if possible.

Comment: Have you thought this through for the case $\vec{u} = \hat{x}$ and  $\vec{v}=\hat{y}$?

Comment: @user52817 In that case $\hat{y}$ is projected onto the 3 coordinate planes and rotated in each one, but the only vector of the 3 that contributes to the sum is the one projected onto the YZ plane because the y and z components of $\hat{u}$ are 0. It doesn't really shed much light on the general case imo. I'd like some picture that explains why this works in the case where all the components of $\hat{u}$ are non-zero.

Comment: @user52817 I want to flesh out the idea that in order to rotate a vector lying in some arbitrary plane by 90 degrees we can project it onto the 3 coordinate planes, rotate those projections by 90 degrees in those planes, and then sum them all together weighted by the components of the plane's normal vector (or alternatively the components of the bivector representing the plane).

Comment: ok now I understand what you are looking for. It is intriguing! All these vectors twisting around.

Comment: It isn't so surprising. $\hat u$ is the diagonal of a brick (parallelepiped) whose sides are $u_x\hat x$, $u_y\hat y$, $u_z\hat z$. If you rotate those  three vectors about any vector $\vec v$, then the whole brick rotates about $\vec v$ by the same angle, and so does the diagonal of the brick.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I think you might have misunderstood the question. I have no problem understanding why rotation is linear, which is what your example demonstrates. What I think is harder to understand is how a 90 degree rotation in some arbitrary plane can be accomplished by projecting the vector onto the 3 coordinate planes, rotating each of those projections in those planes, then summing them (weighted by the components of the original plane's normal vector). I need some pictorial explanation for why this is true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $ \mathbf{\hat{u}} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $ necessarily lie in a plane, so it's possible to decompose $ \mathbf{v} $ into components that lie strictly in that plane.  Suppose $ \{ \mathbf{\hat{f}}_1, \mathbf{\hat{f}}_2 \} $ is a basis for that plane, and further simplify things by setting $ \mathbf{\hat{f}}_1 = \mathbf{\hat{u}} $.  Then we have
$$\mathbf{\hat{u}} = \mathbf{\hat{f}}_1$$
$$\mathbf{v} = v \mathbf{\hat{f}}_1 \cos\theta + v \mathbf{\hat{f}}_2 \sin\theta,$$
where $ v = \left\lVert {\mathbf{v}} \right\rVert $, and $ \mathbf{\hat{f}}_1 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{f}}_2 = 0 $.

With that change of basis made, you now have
$$\mathbf{\hat{u}} \times \mathbf{v}= v \mathbf{\hat{f}}_1 \times \left( { \mathbf{\hat{f}}_1 \cos\theta + \mathbf{\hat{f}}_2 \sin\theta } \right)$$
$$= \left( { \mathbf{\hat{f}}_1 \times \mathbf{\hat{f}}_2 } \right) v \sin\theta.$$
This is a vector is in a direction perpendicular to the plane that $ \mathbf{\hat{u}} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $ lie in, and has the magnitude of the parallelogram formed by $ \mathbf{\hat{u}} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $.

You can now identify the coordinate expressions in your original question.
First let's write $ \mathbf{\hat{w}} = \mathbf{\hat{f}}_1 \times \mathbf{\hat{f}}_2 $ for the direction of that vector perpendicular to the $ \mathbf{\hat{u}}, \mathbf{v} $ plane, so
$$u_x (\mathbf{\hat{x}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}) +u_y (\mathbf{\hat{y}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}) +u_z (\mathbf{\hat{z}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}})= \sin\theta \mathbf{\hat{w}}.$$
Since $ \sin\theta $ is the area of the paralellogram formed by $ \mathbf{\hat{u}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}} $, let's write this as
$$\textrm{Area}(\mathbf{\hat{u}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}})=u_x (\mathbf{\hat{x}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{w}} +u_y (\mathbf{\hat{y}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{w}} +u_z (\mathbf{\hat{z}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{w}},$$
or
$$\textrm{Area}(\mathbf{\hat{u}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}})=u_x \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{\hat{x}} & \mathbf{\hat{v}} & \mathbf{\hat{w}} \end{vmatrix} +u_y \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{\hat{y}} & \mathbf{\hat{v}} & \mathbf{\hat{w}} \end{vmatrix} +u_z \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{\hat{z}} & \mathbf{\hat{v}} & \mathbf{\hat{w}} \end{vmatrix}$$
Each of these triple product determinants represents the volume of the parallelopiped respectively formed by $ \mathbf{\hat{x}}, \mathbf{\hat{y}}, \mathbf{\hat{z}} $ on one edge, and $ \mathbf{\hat{v}}, \mathbf{\hat{w}} $ on the other edges.

We see that the cross product, which can be thought of as an parallelogram area computing machine, can also be recast as a parallopiped volume computing machine, if one of the vectors making extending the parallogram into a volume is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane containing the original two vectors.  That is
$$\textrm{Area}(\mathbf{\hat{u}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}}) = \textrm{Volume}(\mathbf{\hat{u}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}}, \mathbf{\hat{w}}) = \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{\hat{u}} & \mathbf{\hat{v}} & \mathbf{\hat{w}} \end{vmatrix}.$$
or
$$\textrm{Volume}(\mathbf{\hat{u}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}}, \mathbf{\hat{w}})= u_x \textrm{Volume}(\mathbf{\hat{x}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}}, \mathbf{\hat{w}})+ u_y \textrm{Volume}(\mathbf{\hat{y}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}}, \mathbf{\hat{w}})+ u_z \textrm{Volume}(\mathbf{\hat{z}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}}, \mathbf{\hat{w}}).$$
This volume function $ \textrm{Volume}(\mathbf{\hat{u}}, \mathbf{\hat{v}}, \mathbf{\hat{w}}) $ is multilinear.  Of note here is that it is linear in the $ \mathbf{\hat{u}} $ parameter, so we see that the factors $ u_x, u_y, u_z $ represent the weightings of the total volume of this extended space with respect to the volume computation with respect to each of the $ \mathbf{\hat{x}}, \mathbf{\hat{y}}, \mathbf{\hat{z}} $ directions instead of $ \mathbf{\hat{u}} $.

### Aside:

It doesn't actually matter for conceptualizing the geometry of the situtation, but if you want to compute $ \mathbf{\hat{f}}_2 $, or $ \theta $, you can do so by writing
$$\mathbf{v} = (\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{u}}) \mathbf{\hat{u}} + \mathbf{\hat{u}} \times \left( { \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{\hat{u}} } \right),$$
so
$$\cos\theta = \mathbf{\hat{v}} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{u}}$$
$$\mathbf{\hat{f}}_2 \sin\theta = \mathbf{\hat{u}} \times \left( { \mathbf{\hat{v}} \times \mathbf{\hat{u}} } \right).$$